# How do you add Settings.bundle to a phonegap app?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap, settings.bundle

we have implemented a phonegap application using Typescript, Angular, css etc.  We use PhoneGapBuild to package this up and deploy to iPads.

I would now like to add some settings for this app in the iPads settings application - currently, this only shows the permission items like camera, notifications etc.

I have managed to use the cordova plugin "me.apla.cordova.app-preferences" to set and fetch application preference values... but these are not being shown in the Settings app.

Investigating further, I believe that you need to create a Settings.bundle folder with the Root.plist file inside... which I have done (I actually created it using xcode and copied the resulting files into the root of my phonegap project (next to the config.xml))... and still after a PhoneGapBuild and re-deploy nothing appears in the Settings app for my application.  Upon inspection of the .ipa file... the Settings.bundle is location in the www folder... is this correct?

So could someone please tell me the baby steps required to get settings to appear in the Settings app for this type of project.

Comment: Look at David Southers answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511548/cordova-phonegap-ios-app-settings-bundle-possible?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: I had disregarded this answer due to the fact that I would need to run cordova locally to do something (cordova plugin add ./src/ios)... presumably to create the Settings.bundle structure.  If this is the case, then this won't solve my problem which is that PhoneGapBuild will ignore this folder when building the .ipa file (it will end up in the www folder which is of no use - I believe it should be in the root folder, called the app folder or "payload")