# How do I properly add settings to an iOS app with a Cordova project?

Tags: ios, cordova, settings.bundle

In a Cordova build I am trying to add settings for my iOS application. I have the settings already defined in a `Settings.bundle/Root.plist` file. All I want is the `Settings.bundle` copied over to the XCode project along with its children.

I'm trying to do this with a `resource-file` statement:

`<platform name="ios">
    <resource-file src="res/ios/Settings.bundle" />
    ...
</platform>`

When I do my build, the folder is added 3 times to my project instead of only one time, and none of the files inside that folder is copied over. I see in the log output that there are 3 `CpResource` statements executed for this resource.

`CpResource Anamnese\ mobil/Resources/res/ios/Settings.bundle build/emulator/Anamnese\ mobil.app/Settings.bundle
CpResource Anamnese\ mobil/Resources/res/ios/Settings.bundle build/emulator/Anamnese\ mobil.app/Settings.bundle
CpResource Anamnese\ mobil/Resources/res/ios/Settings.bundle build/emulator/Anamnese\ mobil.app/Settings.bundle`

This is consistent with what I'm seeing in the resulting XCode project: The folder is there 3 times, but it has no contents. I played around with the location of the Settings.bundle and the number of file inside to see whether there is a relation to the number of times this is executed, but to no avail.

So, my question is, how do I properly add settings to an iOS app with Cordova?

Or, if I stay on this level of analysis: How do I properly copy folder structures into an iOS project?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find why `resource-file` added the Settings.bundle three times. But I figured out another way to integrate it into the app: I had to declare an own cordova plug-in that listed this Settings.bundle.

David Souther wrote a detailed instruction here: [Cordova Phonegap IOS App Settings.Bundle Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511548/cordova-phonegap-ios-app-settings-bundle-possible?answertab=votes#tab-top)

To install me.apla.cordova.app-preferences I had to also include this line into my `cordova.xml`

`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-preferences" spec="https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences" />`